# How to make user login from only one device at a time

Tags: android, asp.net, iphone, c#-4.0, wcf-rest

I have a RestAPI which when hit authenticate the user.
This api is exposed to android and ios developers they hit this api to allow user to login to our app

My requirement is this.1) If user has cell phone say abc phone with IMEI "abc1234". He logs in from this phone. Now if he tries to log in from his 2nd phone than he should not be allowed to login from 2nd phone. He should first log out from abc device.

now there is few complications
1) if user is logged from abc. With out loging out he formats his phone or uninstalls the app.   Then how should I handle login from same device or other device.

Basically I want to know about strategies or good practises for such type of scenarios.

Comment: auto logout after 5 mins? Forcefully expire the login token every 5 min unless user does some action on the phone. In that case renew the token for next 5 mins.

Comment: Best practices have you covered in situations like User's phone is lost and he is still logged in. Denying login is plainly Loss of Potential business in this case! I would start by listing down all possible situations and weigh the pros and cons of whatever surfaces!

Comment: yes Narasimhan. these scenarios are what i am looking to handle. user is logged in and his phone is lost/format/uninstalls the app. then how will I handle such type of situations. one this is that if user logs in from 2nd device then he is automatically logged out from first device . 2nd solution is if he is logged in from 1 place and tries subsequent login from other place then he should be emailed about this. but i have to store device id in db also

Comment: @iGod, please check my answer.

Comment: Try access token expiry so that you can kill the old logged user from accessing .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SharedPreferences for solution,

For eg.

```
 public class Pref_Storage {
    private static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = null;

    public static void openPref(Context context) {
        sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name),
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public static void deleteKey(Context context, String key) {
        HashMap<String, String> result = new HashMap<String, String>();

        Pref_Storage.openPref(context);
        for (Entry<String, ?> entry : Pref_Storage.sharedPreferences.getAll()
                .entrySet()) {
            result.put(entry.getKey(), (String) entry.getValue());
        }

        boolean b = result.containsKey(key);
        if (b) {
            Pref_Storage.openPref(context);
            Editor prefsPrivateEditor = Pref_Storage.sharedPreferences.edit();
            prefsPrivateEditor.remove(key);

            prefsPrivateEditor.commit();
            prefsPrivateEditor = null;
            Pref_Storage.sharedPreferences = null;
        }
    }

    public static void setDetail(Context context, String key, String value) {
        Pref_Storage.openPref(context);
        Editor prefsPrivateEditor = Pref_Storage.sharedPreferences.edit();
        prefsPrivateEditor.putString(key, value);

        prefsPrivateEditor.commit();
        prefsPrivateEditor = null;
        Pref_Storage.sharedPreferences = null;
    }

    public static Boolean checkDetail(Context context, String key) {
        HashMap<String, String> result = new HashMap<String, String>();

        Pref_Storage.openPref(context);
        for (Entry<String, ?> entry : Pref_Storage.sharedPreferences.getAll()
                .entrySet()) {
            result.put(entry.getKey(), (String) entry.getValue());
        }

        boolean b = result.containsKey(key);
        return b;
    }

    public static String getDetail(Context context, String key) {
        HashMap<String, String> result = new HashMap<String, String>();

        Pref_Storage.openPref(context);
        for (Entry<String, ?> entry : Pref_Storage.sharedPreferences.getAll()
                .entrySet()) {
            result.put(entry.getKey(), (String) entry.getValue());
        }

        String b = result.get(key);
        return b;

    }
}
```

Use:

Before login check login_flag:

```
if (Pref_Storage.checkDetail(getApplicationContext(), "login_flag"))
{
    // Home Screen
}
else
{
    //Display Login Screen
}
```

After Login set login_flag:

```
Pref_Storage.setDetail(getApplicationContext(), "login_flag", "0");
```

Answer (score 26):

Good practice would be let the user login from second device and logged out him from first device it would be better from user experience as well as will be easy to handle e.g

I logged in from `DeviceId A` (update DeviceId in db against the user)
then I try to logged in from `DeviceId B` (again update DeviceId overriding previous DeviceId in db against the user)

Now If I make a request from `DeviceId A`, match the DeviceID in DB, it will return false. Send user back to login page.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you maintain a session for a login. Whenever there is a successful login, you would provide a unique session identifier to the user. This session id can subsequently be used for further requests/calls from the user.


For scenario of user logging in from another number, an active session will mark this second login request as invalid.


Keep an aging mechanism for each session. This way an inactive session, caused by phone getting disconnected or off, will get terminated.

Comment: How will I maintain a unique session when user logs in using android or iphone.

Comment: You could use phone number and device imei to generate the unique string. This string will identify the current session created by this login. Return this to user as a mark of successful login. While you can keep it in a table against the user id.

Answer (score 1):

Hello you can do one thing. Track user login status. like

1. while user login add entry that user is active or login
2. now while user is trying to login with another device at that time check that user is login/active or not. if user is active then don't allow them for login and display message that logout from your old device. You can also put auto logout from last device functionality also.
3. While user is logout at that time change user status active/login to not-active/logout so by this way you can manage this.

You have to pass this user status with your login web Service or API in android and in website you can directly check from DB.

Comment: In your case. if after step 1 user formats the application then his login status is set as active/login. Then there is no other way to log himout

Comment: you can ask user to logout from old device while they try to login from other device. like in facebook and gmail while you change password they are asking you that "Would you like to logout from other devices?" same as you can do this.

Comment: Good idea ,but that doesn`t fit my requirment.

Answer (score 0):

Try, to save a boolean variable. Which will be mark as 0 and the user will be allowed to login. 
On login, the value will be change to 1 and on logout change it back to 0.
User will only be allowed to login when the value of boolean character is 0.

Comment: In your case. if user formats the application after successful login he will always have boolean as 1.

Comment: Then set boolean to 0 if it remains 1 for some days.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharedPreference for storing user login detail after logging and second time you run the app, check that login detail is available or not. And after logout you have to delete shared preference.

For more detail please visit below links:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Answer (score 0):

php example

When user success login

```
$t1 = time();

$t2 = $t1 +10

Save $t1 in redis server

Save $t2 in browser cookie (encrypted, only server know how to decrypt it)
```

Whenever browser visit server always compare that $t2 > $t1, if not send browser message "you are logout"