# how to lock my list view befor purchase in app billing in android?

Tags: java, android

How can I lock my list view before the app purchase?

My list view has 250 stories and I want it so that when a user uses my app the first time he/she can only read 20 stories. When the user purchases the app then he/she can read all the items in a list view.

My list view:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(List View l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    Story story = story's.get(position);

    Intent next = new Intent(this,Show Story.class); 
    next.put Extra("this story", story);
    start Activity(next);
}
```

Comment: Lots of grammar problems with the question fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check below conditions.

```
if(position>20 && story's.get(position) is not purchased)
{
    // open in app purchase screen
}
else
{
    Story story = story's.get(position);

    Intent next = new Intent(this,Show Story.class); 
    next.put Extra("this story", story);
    start Activity(next);
}
```

Comment: true purchase in my app equal m Is Premium = true;        and how edit this code thank;s.     if(position>20 && story's.get(position) is not purchased)

Comment: @M.Mshki, Means you need to manage flag (is purchased or not) for item on that particular position.

Comment: @M.Mshki, add this condition- if(position>20 && Premium != true)

Comment: @M.Mshki, did you get solution?

Comment: not yet. if(position>20 && Premium != true)    no need else

Comment: You have to add else part.

Comment: i use Toast in to if body that user not permium and buy full app

Comment: it work but i exit my app again purchase that mean purchase no save

Comment: Then you have to store the that particular item id on 'Shared Preference' or 'Local Database'

Comment: See my this answer for Shared Preference - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32133584/how-to-make-user-login-from-only-one-device-at-a-time/32349573#32349573

Comment: how save purchase in local database

Comment: You can use Sqlite database for storing purchases

Comment: You can directly set detail by calling Pref_Storage.setDetail(....arguments....) method